# Where are all the recruitment agents?

Tags: euro-truck-simulator-2

Euro Truck Simulator 2 allows you to get multiple trucks and have computer drivers drive them around making you money. These computer drivers are gotten from recruitment agencies. Are all of these recruitment agencies always in the same place?

Where are all of the recruitment agencies?

Answer (score 4):

Here are all the agencies on the map.

Note: The ones from the DLC are missing.
[image: Recruitment]

Answer (score 1):

You discover recruiting agencies in the cities you travel to. On the map they show up as question marks before you discover them, like truck dealers do as well. Once discovered you can recruit drivers  using the main control panel, click on the job agency icon located in lower right corner. Good luck.

Comment: His question was, where those agencies are located, not what they are for :)